# How to get the IP address in client automatically objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I have two Applaction one is the client (IOS device) and the other one is the server (PC device).

I would like to get the ip address in the client (IOS device ) Automatically.

I'm using this line of code to type the IP address

```
NSString *ipAddressText = @"192.168.211.62";
```

I don't want to keep typing the Ip address, becuase the IP address will change most of the time.

here's my code

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad{
            [super viewDidLoad];


            NSString *ipAddressText = @"192.148.211.42";

            NSLog(@"Setting up connection to %@ : %i", ipAddressText, 111);
            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) ipAddressText, 111, &readStream, &writeStream);
            messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [self open];
        }

    - (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

        NSLog(@"stream event %lu \n ", streamEvent);

        switch (streamEvent) {

            case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
                NSLog(@"Stream opened");
                _connectedLabel.text = @"Connected";
                break;
            case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

                if (theStream == inputStream)
                {
                    uint8_t buffer[1024];
                    NSInteger len;

                    while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
                    {
                        len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                        if (len > 0)
                        {
                            NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                            if (nil != output)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"server said: %@ \n ", output);
                                [self messageReceived:output];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
                NSLog(@"Stream has space available now");
                break;

            case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
                NSLog(@"%@\n",[theStream streamError].localizedDescription);
                break;

            case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

                [theStream close];
                [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
                _connectedLabel.text = @"Disconnected";
                NSLog(@"close stream");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Unknown event");
        }

    }

        - (void)open {

            NSLog(@"Opening streams.");

            outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
            inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;

            [outputStream setDelegate:self];
            [inputStream setDelegate:self];

            [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            [outputStream open];
            [inputStream open];

             _connectedLabel.text = @"Connected";
        }


    - (void)close {
        NSLog(@"Closing streams.");
        [inputStream close];
        [outputStream close];
        [inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [inputStream setDelegate:nil];
        [outputStream setDelegate:nil];
        inputStream = nil;
        outputStream = nil;

        _connectedLabel.text = @"Disconnected";
    }
```

Comment: This is what DNS is for

Comment: @Paulw11 is there any way to read the IP address Automatically from the server. Thank you

Comment: If they are on the same network you could use a broadcast/multicast protocol like bonjour

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, They both using the same Network, but I would like to use TCP instead of broadcast/multicast

Comment: You can use broadcast and multicast with TCP but in this case you can use uni cast TCP once you know the server's address. Your problem is that you need to identify your server's IP. If you don't have DNS or a static address then you need to have something listening on the server for a broadcast/multicast and respond to a packet from the client. Bonjour can do this for you

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your time, do you have any example that show how to do that in objective c.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in Swift, but can easily be dropped into any Xcode project.

NB: This example is taken from a GitHub project [Host.swift](https://github.com/rjstelling/Host.swift).

Getting information about network interfaces in Unix type systems like iOS or Mac OS X requires using some arcane C APIs. These APIs have varying amounts of visibility in [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) and [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) and [mac-os-x](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x).

If you're exclusively targeting macOS with Objective-C, then [nshost](/questions/tagged/nshost) is your best solution. However, if you require iOS compatibility then you'll have to drop down to lower level C API such as `getifaddrs(...)` or [cfhost](/questions/tagged/cfhost).

If you want a [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) based solution even `getifaddrs(...)` comes with some bridging header requirements (making it unusable in a Framework).

Here is an example using `CFHost` and `sockaddr_in struct` that will work in Swift and on macOS and iOS (even in Frameworks). See [Host.swift](https://github.com/rjstelling/Host.swift/blob/master/Host.swift) on GitHib for a fully working example.

1. Use `CFHost` to get the addressing info, this will be a `CFArray` of `CFData` objets.

   ```
   let sockaddrs = CFHostGetAddressing("apple.com", &resolved)?.takeRetainedValue()
   ```
2. Get the first object

   ```
   let data = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sockaddrs, 0)
   ```
3. Cast the bytes into a `sockaddr struct`

   ```
   var storage = sockaddr_storage()
   data.getBytes(&storage, length: sizeof(sockaddr_storage))
   ```
4. Then force the `sockaddr struct` into a `sockaddr_in struct` so we can use it

   ```
   let addr = withUnsafePointer(&storage) { UnsafePointer<sockaddr_in>($0).memory
   ```
5. Use the `inet_ntoa(...)` function to turn `addr.sin_addr` (IP address) into a C-string. We can then use `String(Cstring: encoding:)` to get a nice String of the IP Address.

   ```
   let address = String(CString: inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   ```

Here is a GitHub project called [Host.swift](https://github.com/rjstelling/Host.swift) that I created to solve these issues using the technique above.